# Node.js - how to attach properties to one single object in multiple files?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to attach a lot of properties to a single object. I do not want to do this in one single file. Is the example below a correct and good way to break this into multiple files?

For example, in `main.js`,

```
var obj = {};

obj = require('./utils');
obj = require('./part1');
// other requires omitted...

obj.init = function() {
  obj.util1();
  obj.helper1();
};

module.exports = obj;
```

in `utils.js`,

```
var obj = require('./main');

obj.util = function() {
  console.log('util1');
};

// other methods omitted...

module.exports = obj;
```

in `part1.js`,

```
var obj = require('./main');

obj.helper1= function() {
  obj.util1();
  console.log('helper1');
};

// other methods omitted...

module.exports = obj;
```

and there are `part2.js`, `part3.js`, etc.

You see there is circular dependency in the files. Is there a better way than the example above?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9400396/362536

Comment: @Brad My question seems to be irrelevant to deep copy or extend.

Comment: Am I not understanding your question?  Seems like all you want to do is `require()` multiple files and combine the exported objects into one.

Comment: I mean, is it circular dependency is a good way to attach properties to one single object in multiple files?

Comment: Yes I want to `require` multiple files and combine the exported objects into one. But any of these files may also refer to methods defined in another file. Think `jQeury` object.

Comment: It doesn't matter what these other files do.  What matters is the exported object.  You can combine that object with other objects easily.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14659/discussion-between-powerboy-and-brad)