# Why cant parse JSON from file?

Tags: json, node.js

We have empty JSON file
I want to write new JSON objects in this file, and get from it Array of JSON objects (and after simply append new JSONs to array by 'push')
I write to the file incoming JSON object:

```
fs.writeFileSync(tasks, updatedJsonStr, encoding='utf8');
```

where

```
updatedJsonStr = JSON.stringify({"isCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"});
```

So in the file we see added object.
After we get from the file our JSON objects:

```
tasksJsonObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json", "utf-8"));
```

Append new JSON object as string and write it again:

```
updatedJsonStr = JSON.stringify(tasksJsonObj) + ',' +  JSON.stringify(newJsonTask);
```

fs.writeFileSync(tasks, updatedJsonStr, encoding='utf8');
So we see 2 JSON objects in the file.
!But when I try to read file with 2 JSON objects - I got an error when reading JSON from the file ([SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,]):

```js
 try{
    tasksJsonObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(tasks, "utf-8"));
    console.log('aaaaa' + JSON.stringify(tasksJsonObj));
    return true;
  }catch (err) {
    console.log("its not ok!");
    console.log(err);
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: "I got an error" - hey, I'm all for suspenseful writing in  literature, but here I'd rather you actually told us *what* error you got. Also, adding an appropriate tag for what language/technology you're working with would also be good. At a *guess*, [tag:node.js]?

Comment: nodeJS, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,"

Comment: When you give an error, you have to specify the full error and **the line at which it occured**. Edit your question with the "edit" link to include it.

Comment: I guess you're using JavaScript? right? Anyways there's a little problem with what you are writing. If you want to have multiple JSONs next to each other, you should consider putting them into an array: `updatedJsonStr = []; updatedJsonStr.push(JSON.stringify(tasksJsonObj)); updatedJsonStr.push(JSON.stringify(newJsonTask));` and then write them into file!

Comment: @Spacemaster you can use '@' to notify the person (like I did). And also accept my answer below to do everyone a favor as well as yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON formation is wrong,

```
{"isCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"}, {"newisCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"}
```

this is what you will get after concat two JSON stringify, which is also invalid.

Your JSON should be like this

```
[ {"isCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"}, {"newisCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"} ]
```

for that you can do something like this

```
var tasks = [];
tasks.push( {"isCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"}) );
```

so your update jsonstr would be

```
updatedJsonStr = JSON.stringify( tasks );
```

again if you want to append a new json string, you can do like this

```
tasksJsonObj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json", "utf-8"));
tasksJsonObj.push( newJsonTask );
```

and then stringify it and write it back to file.

Comment: So when I try to push new JSON element to main array:

var TasksJsonArray = [];

function readJsonContent() {
  try{
    TasksJsonArray = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(tasks, "utf-8"));
...
....
TasksJsonArray.push(JSON.stringify(newJsonTask));

I got an error 
'undefined is not a function'
on line where try to push ..

Comment: You can only push object not json string, do like this TasksJsonArray.push( newJsonTask );

Comment: Thank you so much .. tryed to know much time how to organize this infernal mechanism ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to "extend" the object:

https://lodash.com/docs#assign

[deep extend (like jQuery's) for nodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399365/deep-extend-like-jquerys-for-nodejs)

If you are trying to "push" new objects into an array, then you're almost there:

```
var updatedJsonStr = JSON.stringify([{"isCompleted":false,"task":"dfgdfg","date":"25.06.2015"}]);

fs.writeFileSync(tasks, updatedJsonStr, encoding='utf8');

var tasksJsonArr = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("tasks.json", "utf-8"));

tasksJsonArr.push(newJsonTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a little problem with what you are writing. If you want to have multiple JSONs next to each other, you should consider putting them into an array:

```
updatedJsonStr = [];
updatedJsonStr.push(JSON.stringify(tasksJsonObj));
updatedJsonStr.push(JSON.stringify(newJsonTask));
```

and then write them into file!